# mysql select where if variable is set

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- sales
- sales_sizes

I want to do a query for sales_sizes constrained by the variables $gender, $category and $brand.

How do I do a where statement if the individual variables are set, and don't include them in the query if they are not set?

[pseudo code in brackets]

```
SELECT size, country
FROM `sales_sizes` WHERE sale_id IN (
    SELECT sale_id
    FROM `sales`
    WHERE [gender = $gender if $gender isset]
    AND [category = $category if $category isset]
    AND [brand = $brand if $brand isset]

)
```

Comment: are you using PDO or create a query as text?

Comment: build the querry in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gather your variables into array and then handle it like this:

```
$gender   = 'f';
$category = null;
$brand    = 'foo';

$rgCondition = ['gender'=>$gender, 'category'=>$category, 'brand'=>$brand];
$rgCondition = array_filter($rgCondition, function($x)
{
   //strip null-ed values:
   return isset($x);
});
$rgWhere     = [];

foreach($rgCondition as $sField=>$mValue)
{
   $rgWhere[] = '`'.$sField.'` = "'.$mValue.'"';   
}
$sWhere = count($rgWhere)?' WHERE '.join(' && ', $rgWhere):'';
//var_dump($sWhere);
```

-I've skipped strings escaping, but do not forget it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE statement
UPDATE: The previous syntax (as pointed out by a few people) doesn't work. You can use CASE as follows:

```
SELECT size, country
FROM `sales_sizes` WHERE sale_id IN (
    SELECT sale_id
    FROM `sales`
    WHERE [gender = $gender if $gender isset]
    AND [category = $category if $category isset]
    AND [brand = $brand if $brand isset]

)

WHERE gender
  CASE WHEN gender ($gender) = isset THEN 
    $gender 
  ELSE
    $gender='NULL'
  END
```

Comment: this won't work, look at case statement syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html